# How to retrieve the last child of a JSON that don't contain a specific key

Tags: python, json

I'd like to know how to read the last child that doesn't have the "children" key in it.

Here is my json :

```
{
"children": [
    {
        "data" : {
            "title" : "Legume",
            "attr" : { id: 001 }
        },
        "children" : [
            {
                "data" : {
                    "title" : "Legume frais",
                    "attr" : { id: 007 }
                },
                "children" : [
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Cumcumber",
                        "attr" : { id: 666 }
                    },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Tomato",
                        "attr" : { id: 777 }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data" : {
            "title" : "Fruit",
            "attr" : { id: 002 }
        },
        "children" : [
            {
                "data" : {
                    "title" : "fruit rouge",
                    "attr" : { id: 333 }
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data" : {
            "title" : "Viande",
            "attr" : { id: 003 }
        },
        "children" : [
            {
                ....
            }
        ]
    },
]}
```

Here, I'd like to retrieve this part:

```
 "data" : {
           "title" : "Cumcumber",
           "attr" : { id: 666 }
          },
```

I know how to retrieve this part from a defined depth level. But in my full json, the depth level can be different for each wanted element. How can I be sure to grab the last child that don't have a "children" key ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list-comprehension to create a sub-list from your original json, and than get the last element of that new sub-list. Something like the following should work:

```
data = { "records" : [{ "empid": 1, "fname": "X" }, { "empid": 2, "fname": "A", "lname": "Y" }, { "empid": 3, "fname": "B", "lname": "Y" }, { "empid": 4, "fname": "C", "lname": "Y" }, { "empid": 5, "fname": "C", "lname": "Y" }] }
foo = [d for d in data['records'] if not 'lname' in d]
foo[len(foo)-1]
>> {'empid': 1, 'fname': 'X'}
```